# How to load host.conf file variables in lua script

Tags: lua

I need to load configuration variables from .conf file in lua script, and use those variables to connect to a database. I have tried using:

```
require "host.conf"
loadfile("host.conf") - error with unexpected token '#' 
os.execute("pathToConfFile/host.lua") - and I have created a lua host file with variables in bash shell
io.popen("host.conf") etc..
```

None of these solutions are valid.
Is there a way to use the existing host.conf file in lua, and avoid the unexpected token error?
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Firstly, have you researched each of those functions and what they actually do? Each has its own purpose, meaning that they are not interchangeable. Secondly, how do you intend to connect to the database that you mention? Are you using a library that has a Lua API? And, finally, what system and version of Lua are you using?

Comment: Anw what is the content of `host.conf` (censor the sensitive data, or course).

Comment: Unexpected token '#' points to comments in host.conf and so not a Lua script.

Comment: did you consider reading the Lua manual? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by stuffing a filename into some random functions. How can you expect anything useful from doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
local original = io .open('host.conf')
local hostconf = {}  --  copy contents into Lua table

for line in original :lines() do
    table .insert( hostconf, line )
end ; io .close( original )

print( hostconf[1] )  --  prints line 1
```

You haven't specified what format your host.conf comes in, but you'll likely want to parse it better than just throwing contents in a list.  Perhaps splitting each line into head / tail, based upon a delimiter ( comma, space, whatever you have between variable & value )

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone who helped out. My question wasn't precise and I had more to learn before I have asked and sorry about that. This is what I used to solve the problem.

```
local open = io.open

local function read_file(path)
    local file = open(path, "r")
    if not file then return nil end
    local content = file:read "*a" -- *a or *all reads the whole file

    local lines = {}

    for line in io.lines(path) do
        --print(line);
        if(line:find(var)~=nil)then
           local varStart=string.len(var)+2
           local varEnd=string.len(line)
           var=string.sub(line,varStart,varEnd)
           print(var);
        end
--repeat for every line
    
    end
    file:close()
    return lines;
end

local fileContent = read_file("path");
```